# Photoshop simulating printer (lack of white ink) on colored paper

Tags: adobe-photoshop, color, print-design

I want to print something on colored paper. Is it possible to simulate lack of white ink in printer in Photoshop?

I am worried that some colors may be to bright to be actually visible on colored paper or they will be much darker than i expect.

Comment: Are you certain you mean "lack of"? It sounds more like you want to simulate white ink to make bright colors brighter. (which can't be done by the way).